# Mac OS X Server 10.6.7: Disable Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx-server

I'm doing some Rails dev, and I'm trying to get [Pow](http://pow.cx) running. After making the appropriate symlink, if I try to go to `idealm_web.dev/` (`idealm_web` being the name of my Rails project), I get this:

[image: It's gorgeous, but useless right now.]

I was told that this was Apache. How do I disable this? I checked under System Preferences > Sharing, and there was no way to disable it.

[Cross-posted from AskDifferent, [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14266/mac-os-x-server-10-6-7-disable-apache). Are we allowed to do this?]

EDIT: Here is a screengrab of System Preferences > Sharing. I don't see Web Sharing anywhere, and this is where OSX pointed me when I typed in 'web sharing' in Spotlight.

[image]

Comment: Turn off Web Sharing. You might have to restart. There are other ways of doing it also. Keep searching.

Comment: What are some of these other ways? I have been searching already - that's why I posted here. Please see my edit of the question.

Comment: No, please do not crosspost. Apple.SE is for end users, this is a server question and belongs on ServerFault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is different with the Server version of OS X: You need to start the `Server Admin` application (likely under `/Applications/Server`) and deactivate the Web service there. Alternatively, use the terminal and issue the command `sudo serveradmin stop web`.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because the default virtual host in Mac OS X Server's Apache configuration answers to *. You can turn off Apache as other answers have suggested, or you can use the Server Admin utility, edit the Web Service settings, and take out that wildcard to see if that helps.